# How to implement sequential queries for an API under AJAX and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

There is a URL, where an API of work orders is hosted. The API provides a method that delivers the headers of work orders for a client and on a date. What it returns is a code of the work order. There is a second method where, with the work order code, it returns the detail of this order.

Unfortunately the API does not have a method that brings me at once the header and detail of the work order. I need to have the complete information of each work order, its header and its details.

Given the above, my strategy has been to make a small routine in jQuery that first via AJAX invokes an API method that delivers all the headers of the work orders, for a given date and a specific client. These headers store them in an array. After the above, I go through this arrangement and invoke another method of the API to obtain the respective details of the work orders, which can be one or several records.

The problem is that when executing, all the headers are obtained, but when the query of the details is executed, the server responds with a message:

```
Sorry, we have detected that there are simultaneous requests
```

without being able to obtain the details. Investigating the subject, everything makes reference that a problem with the subject of AJAX and its asynchrony occurs. That the detailed consultations are being done in parallel and must be carried out sequentially, for which purpose it must be implemented with `Promise`.

With a little help, I made the changes, but I still get the same error.

The implementation is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn_nuevo").click(function() {
        var ocs = [];
        var total = 0;
        $('#result').append('<b>total 1: </b>' + total + '<br />');
        //ESTE PRIMER AJAX OBTIENE LA LISTA DE OT
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://api.ot.json?fecha=26062018&Cliente=100ticket=C7A82D65",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            //TOTAL DE OT
            total = data.Cantidad;

            //SE ALMACENAN LAS OT
            for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
              ocs[i + 1] = data.Listado[i].Codigo;
            };

            $('#result').append('<b>total 1: </b>' + total + '<br />');

            let promise;
            let j = 0;
            let url = "http://api.ot.json?codigo=" + ocs[j + 1] + "&ticket=C7A82D65";

            for (let j = 0; j < total; j++) {
              if (j === 0) {
                promise = promise || $.ajax({
                  url: url,
                  dataType: "json"
                });
                j++;
              } else {
                promise = promise.then(datos => {
                  $('#result').append('<b>Codigo: </b>' + datos.Listado[0].Codigo + '<br />');
                  $('#result').append('<b>Nombre: </b>' + datos.Listado[0].Nombre + '<br />');
                  $('#result').append('<b>Estado: </b>' + datos.Listado[0].Estado + '<br />');
                  $('#result').append('<b>Descripcion: </b>' + datos.Listado[0].Descripcion + '<br />');
                  $('#result').append('<b>Tipo: </b>' + datos.Listado[0].Tipo + '<br />');
                  url = "http://api.ot.json?codigo=" + ocs[j + 1] + "&ticket=C7A82D65";
                  return $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json"
                  });
                });
              }
            };
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="boton_nuevo" align="center">
    <input type="button" id="btn_nuevo" name="btnnuevo" value="Ejecutar">
  </div>
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error message is as follows:

[image: Sample Image]

---

[image: Sample Image]

Can anybody help me?

---

I have proceeded to carry out the modification indicated by Jaromanda in http://jsfiddle.net/qj80ovw5/2/.

When executing with the modification, it has been possible to obtain the detail of the first work order, something that was not previously possible, but after bringing the data of this first one, the server sends the same error indicated initially in the question.

Apparently, the server keeps coming in parallel queries and that's why the server responds in that way. How could this recovery of the details of work orders be improved, so that this error does not occur?

http://jsfiddle.net/qj80ovw5/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn_nuevo").click(function() {
    $('#result').append('<b>total 1: </b>' + total + '<br />');
    //ESTE PRIMER AJAX OBTIENE LA LISTA DE OT
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://api.ot.json?fecha=26062018&Cliente=100ticket=C7A82D65",
      dataType: "json"
    }).then(data => {
      const total = data.Cantidad;

      $('#result').append('<b>total 1: </b>' + total + '<br />');

      let promise = Promise.resolve(); // or $.when() 

      for (let j = 0; j < total; j++) {
        let url = "http://api.ot.json?codigo=" + data.Listado[i].Codigo + "&ticket=C7A82D65";
        promise = promise
          .then(() => $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "json"
          }))
          .then(datos => {
            $('#result').append('<b>Codigo: </b>' + datos.Listado[0].Codigo + '<br />');
            $('#result').append('<b>Nombre: </b>' + datos.Listado[0].Nombre + '<br />');
            $('#result').append('<b>Estado: </b>' + datos.Listado[0].Estado + '<br />');
            $('#result').append('<b>Descripcion: </b>' + datos.Listado[0].Descripcion + '<br />');
            $('#result').append('<b>Tipo: </b>' + datos.Listado[0].Tipo + '<br />');
          });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: the code looks like it should do what you want - though there will never be a request where j == 1

Comment: This is a much more sane pattern - http://www.jefferydurand.com/jquery/sequential/javascript/ajax/2015/04/13/jquery-sequential-ajax-promise-deferred.html

Comment: Your code can be written - https://jsfiddle.net/qj80ovw5/

Comment: or even https://jsfiddle.net/qj80ovw5/2/ and maybe https://jsfiddle.net/qj80ovw5/5/

Comment: Does this issue occur on a single click of `$("#btn_nuevo")` ?

Comment: That's right, the button is only for the whole logic to run; I press it once.

Comment: well, your code, other than the fact it **will skip j == 1** seems to be correct, despite the overcomplicated way you implemented it - also, if `total == 1` you'd never get **any** *datos* output at all

Comment: also `promise = promise ||` is redundant, since when `j === 0` `promise` will definitely be `undefined` - but again, there shouldn't be any simultaneous requests happening - which version of jQuery do you use? I've seen very odd "Promise" behaviour in some old jQuery

Comment: I'm using: jQuery v1.10.2

I do not know if Jquery's version is very old and the problem is due to that?